# What is the minhag followed in the Bnei Tzion Siddur?

Tags: prayer-book, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, nusach-edot-hammizrach

Bnei Tzion is an Israeli siddur published in 1996 by Sinai Publishing in Tel Aviv. It's a Sephardi siddur but has some interesting variants (e.g., very similar Havdalah to Ashkenazi practice). I'm looking to find out the specific Sephardic group(s) that use this siddur.

Comment: It's full of mistakes. A lot of Iranian Jews use it though. Their Rabbis rally against it. The first editions were published much earlier, in the 70's

Comment: user6521, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks for bringing this interesting question! Please edit [your user profile](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1200/user6521) and give yourself a name, unless you have some special attachment to 6521.

Comment: @HahuGavra, that sounds like an answer, especially if you flesh it out more (e.g., can you name any rabbis, specifically, who rally against it?). You might wish to post it as such.

Comment: @HahuGavra If you can also include some specific things in the siddur to which they object, it would be helpful to know. Thanks and best.

Answer (score 5):

I bought a "pocket edition" of Sidur Bnei Tzion from a bookstore in Paris in 2006; it is almost identical in order and contents (although more reduced) to a Sidur used by Congregation Beth-El of Rio de Janeiro (Brazil). Their Sidur, called "Siddur Matzliach Melamed" was compiled by Rabbi Meir Matzliach Melamed for a Portuguese/Hebrew Edition in the 1960's. He was of Turkish descent, so I believe those are mostly Sefaradim of Levantine origins in General.

Comment: user2256, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for sharing this information! Please consider editing [your user profile](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2256/user2256) to give yourself a name, unless you have some special affection for the number 2256.

Answer (score 1):

The siddur with same name is used by Jews in Serbia, Sefardi mostly. Today we have new edition but it is based on Serbian edition from the beginning of 20th century.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Ana! Thanks for posting this answer. Hopefully you can continue to contribute your unique knowledge to the site. To learn more about the site consider taking the following short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour).